# Connecting to open shift with Jconsole - non-JRMP server at remote endpoint

Tags: java, jboss, remote-access, openshift, jconsole

I am trying to connect to an open shift application using jconsole. I am following the guide located here https://www.openshift.com/forums/openshift/accesing-jmx-mbean-as-7-app which says that after using rhc port forward we should get an output - mine looks as follows

```
Checking available ports ... done
Forwarding ports ...
Address already in use - bind(2) while forwarding port 8080. Trying local port
8081
Address already in use - bind(2) while forwarding port 8080. Trying local port
8081
Address already in use - bind(2) while forwarding port 8081. Trying local port
8082

To connect to a service running on OpenShift, use the Local address

Service Local                OpenShift
------- --------------- ---- ---------------------------------------------------
haproxy 127.0.0.1:8080   =>  127.2.167.2:8080
haproxy 127.0.0.1:8081   =>  127.2.167.3:8080
java    127.0.0.1:3528   =>  127.2.167.1:3528
java    127.0.0.1:4447   =>  127.2.167.1:4447
java    127.0.0.1:5445   =>  127.2.167.1:5445
java    127.0.0.1:5455   =>  127.2.167.1:5455
java    127.0.0.1:8082   =>  127.2.167.1:8080
java    127.0.0.1:9990   =>  127.2.167.1:9990
java    127.0.0.1:9999   =>  127.2.167.1:9999
mysql   127.0.0.1:40381  =>  537275e04382ec4bcf00008e-hnwebservice.rhcloud.com:40381

Press CTRL-C to terminate port forwarding
```

Based on the guide, it then continues to say that i can connect using the home address - in my case i would want to use the following value `127.0.0.1:9999` - when i try to do this i get the following error

`Connection failed: non-JRMP server at remote endpoint`

Please could someone help me in understanding what this error means and maybe how to solve it?

Thanks

Comment: My first trouble shooting would be to hit 127.0.0.1:9999 with telnet. Then I would put in the web broswer and see what comes up. 

Why Java cart did you use to create this app?

Comment: The meaning of the message is that you are trying to talk RMI to a non-RMI endpoint, or possibly an RMI/SSL endpoint. But why in this configuration is another question.